# Formatting flask-wtf submit button using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using jinja to render a flask-wtf submit button as follows:

```
{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
```

This results in a button formatted in btn-default bootstrap format (white). I'd like to change this to btn-success bootstrap format (green).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are also using flask-bootstrap.

On the flask-bootstrap Jinja2 macros you have:

```
    {% call _hz_form_wrap(horizontal_columns, form_type, True, required=required) %}
    {{field(class='btn btn-%s' % button_map.get(field.name, 'default'), **kwargs)}}
    {% endcall %}
```

You should use if you can the button_map to do it [see details in comments below]

Comment: I am indeed also using flask-bootstrap. I'm afraid I do not follow your suggestion though. Can you elaborate a bit further please?

Comment: please see if this helps on the docs: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#quick_form or http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#form_field

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by @dpgaspar the solution was to use button_map as follows:

```
{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit, button_map={'submit':'success'}) }}
```

Comment: what is 'submit' referencing in the button map dict?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but it is the "name" attribute. i feel like flask-bootstrap docs are kind of weak here...

Answer (score 9):

If you are using wtf.quick_form, use the form like this.

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, button_map={'submit':'success'}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flask-bootstrap, use the form with button_map as suggested by @dpgaspar,

For whole form - wtf.quick_form:

```
{{wtf.quick_form(delete_form, button_map={'name_of_field': 'danger'})}}
```

For individual field, wtf.form_field:

```
{{wtf.form_field(delete_form.delete, button_map={'delete': 'success'})}}
```

Flask-Bootstrap official [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html) says:

> button_map – A dictionary, mapping button field names to names such as primary, danger or success. Buttons not found in the button_map will use the default type of button.